# MySQL EAV Database: Indexes not being utilised for queries using OR with LEFT JOINs (Wordpress DB)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, indexing, entity-attribute-value

We have a query on a Wordpress site (EAV database) that is very slow because it's failing to use the relevant index. Here's a simplified version of the offending query:

```
SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1 ON p.ID = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = 'm1' 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2 ON p.ID = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = 'm2' 
WHERE  m1.meta_value = '1' OR m2.meta_value = '1'
```

This takes about 15 seconds to return 200 results.

EXPLAIN shows that it uses the indexes for m1 and m2, but has to search 200k rows of wp_posts (Using index; Using filesort)

We can rearrange the query, and it runs in ~0.1 seconds:

```
SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1 ON p.ID = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = 'm1' 
WHERE  m1.meta_value = '1' 

UNION ALL

SELECT p.ID FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2 ON p.ID = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = 'm2' 
WHERE  m2.meta_value = '1';
```

EXPLAIN shows that it uses the indexes on m1 and m2 (as before), but now uses the Primary key on wp_posts (once for each SELECT).

Interestingly, if the OR had been an AND in the original query it would have been very fast.

Because this is a Wordpress plugin, I'd rather not re-write the original query.
I had been hoping to find a way to re-index the tables that would help, or to find a way to teach MySQL how to run the original query more efficiently, but this seems unrealistic.

If anyone does know *why* the OR makes all the difference, I'd be very interested to understand.

Comment: WP's "meta" tables are poorly indexed.  This plugin fixes that:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: You cannot do much, unfortunately. This has been a bane for mysql for a long time!

Comment: This question's been marked as a duplicate - the linked-to answer gives the UNION as the solution. My question is *why* the OR makes all the difference. I'd still be grateful if anyone has any thoughts to add to comments even if they can't post!